# For which $n\geq2$ does there exist $\sigma \in A_n$ with $|\sigma|>n$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups, permutation-cycles

> For which $n\geq2$ does there exist $\sigma \in A_n$ with $|\sigma|>n$?

I have found this same question [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4081409/for-which-n%E2%89%A52-does-there-exist-sigma-in-a-n-with-sigma-n), But I have not been able to understand how it works.

On my own I came to the conclusion that for $n$ less than $8$ the result is not satisfied, but for $n = 8$, I found the permutation $\sigma$ formed by a $5$-cycle and a $3$-cycle. Which is in $A_n$ and $|\sigma|=15>8$. In particular, I cannot understand how the proof follows, to conclude that the result is true for all $n\geq 8$. Could you help me? If there is an easier way to see this, please, I would appreciate if you shared it.

Comment: I find the proof given by the person who posted the linked question rather clear. I think you should as a more concrete question: which part(s) of that proof you don't understand?

Comment: Consider the $2$-cycle $(1 2)$ and the $3$-cycle $(3 4 5)$ in $S_5$. Their product has order $6>5$.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang But their product are not in $A_n$. This permutation is odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $n$ consider taking a $3$-cycle and a cycle of length $l$ where $l$ is the largest number less than or equal to $n-3$ that is not a multiple of $3$ nor a multiple of $2$. Notice we have $l\geq n-6$ ( because it is not possible for $n-3,n-4,n-5$ and $n-6$ to all be even or multiples of $3$).

It follows that there is an element of order at least $3(n-6)$, and we have $3(n-6)> n$ for $n>9$.

For $n=9$ we can take a $3$-cycle and a $5$-cycle.

For $n=8$ we can take a $3$-cycle and a $5$-cycle.

Hence the only cases we must check are $n=1,2,3,4,5,6,7$ (which apparently is what you did).

Comment: Could you please tell me, why exactly do you say that $3(n-6)> n$ for $n> 9$? 
What value is $n$ supposed to be taking?

Comment: I mean that the inequality $3(n-6) > n$ holds for every $n>9$.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry. I understand, thank you